# Custom hook doesn't work when called on button click

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I'm having trouble on finding what is wrong with this SQL statement. I'm using `pyodbc` latest and `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`, here is the statement:

```
insert_sql = """MERGE VehicleDistanceReport trg
                            USING (VALUES (?, ?, ?))
                            src(
                            Distance,
                            Ic_Siparis_No,
                            Vehicle_Hour
                            )
                                    ON trg.Ic_Siparis_No = src.Ic_Siparis_No
                            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                                    UPDATE SET 
                                    Distance = src.Distance,
                                    Ic_Siparis_No = src.Ic_Siparis_No,
                                    Vehicle_Hour = src.Vehicle_Hour
                                    WHERE trg.NodeGroup LIKE N'%AĞIR%' OR trg.NodeGroup LIKE N'%MAKİNE%'
                            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                                    INSERT(
                                        id,
                                        Record_No,
                                        Device_No,
                                        License_Plate,
                                        Inı
                                        Distance,
                                        Ic_Siparis_No,
                                        Vehicle_Hour
                                        )                                        
                                    VALUES(
                                        src.Distance,
                                        src.Ic_Siparis_No,
                                        src.Vehicle_Hour
                                        );"""
```

It says there is a syntax error near `WHERE` statement but the query seems to work in SQL server.

Comment: In the `NOT MATCHED` section, you can't have `INSERT ... VALUES ... WHERE`.

Comment: Yes I've noticed that but the same error occurs when I delete that statement too.

Comment: similarly for the `WHEN MATCHED` section, you need to remove the `WHERE` clause. move it up to `WHEN MATCHED AND  (trg.NodeGroup LIKE N'%AĞIR%' OR trg.NodeGroup LIKE N'%MAKİNE%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHEN MATCHED` clause is wrong, as the `WHERE` should be a condition. Also no pooint updating `Ic_Siparis_No` as it's the joining condition anyway

```sql
WHEN MATCHED AND trg.NodeGroup LIKE N'%AĞIR%' OR trg.NodeGroup LIKE N'%MAKİNE%' THEN
    UPDATE SET 
    Distance = src.Distance,
    Vehicle_Hour = src.Vehicle_Hour
```

Don't be tempted to place this condition in the `ON` clause, it will cause incorrect results.